# Video Livestream Editor

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

We're planing some kind of video livestreaming with two different sources we'd like to switch.

So there will be two livestreams going to the editing person that should be able to choose which livestream video should be shown at that moment and should be able to switch the source without a interruption in streaming. The editing person will stream the video then to youtube or another livestreaming service.

Is there any free software out there to do that? It shouldn't be a console tool. I know that some streaming servers offer a feature to switch sources on the fly, but it should best come with a gui for the editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to spend on a hardware switcher, which will be expensive, you can try the software alternatives.

http://www.telestream.net/wirecast/

http://www.dvmixer.com/

http://www.avtake.com/cutfour.asp

Answer (score 0):

I had done some live broadcasts with different programs, and I want to recommend [**vMix**](http://www.vmixhd.com/). Very good program. It can synchronize sources to each other, easily switch between them, adjust the sound, add effects...[image]
Video about vMix: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8inGve-4GQw